# Russian language automatically loads on windows 7 startup

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, input-languages, language-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Russian Language in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/398905/russian-language-in-windows-7)

i am using windows 7 ultimate edition.

I did a fresh installation. And only programs I installed is Gameranger and silverlight.

Now when I run my pc i see language bar on my desktop. two languages are present in it english and russian. However i have not enabled russian lanaguage.

When i go to language settings only english is present and there is no russian present in it. I then add russian language, apply changes, and then remove russian language then russian language is removed.

but when i restart my pc russian lanaguage is still present there. what is problem.