# Russian Language in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, input-languages

I am using windows 7 64 bit ultimate edition.

i ran my pc. windows opened.
on the top i see language bar. which shows that there are two languages present one is english and other is russian.

[image: Windows Load]

After that i go to language settings. Here i see that only english language is there. there is no russian language present.

[image: Keyboard settings]

there is no russian keyboard here but i still see language bar. then i add russian language in to the list, applied it, and then remove russian language from the list and then i click ok. now russian language is gone. what should i do that it doesnt load at the start.

Comment: Are you using a legal non-hacked version of windows 7?

Comment: I am not sure what your actual question is.  Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @Shinrai when i start my windows then it is shown that two input language (keyboard layouts) are loaded. one is english and one is russian. point to ponder is that i havent added russian language. When i go to keyboard layout settings it shows me that only english is in the list and there is no russian. but the language bar shows me russian is present as well. in normal case if u have only english language as input language bar doesnt show. but in my case only english is in the list but i see two languages.

Comment: i want to know how to get rid of russian language permanently. what now i do is everytime i start my pc i go and delete russian language,

Comment: This happens by default if you set your language to English and your locale to Russia. It's for currency, time, etc, not the actual interface language - that's why the keyboard is only English.  I assume you want your locale to stay Russia, so just do what HaydnWVN suggests in that answer to hide the language bar.

Comment: i m not russian. i live in pakistan. if it is due to location then urdu (language of pakistan) should be added instead of russian langauge,

Comment: Is this an OEM machine?  It might have originally been configured with those region options.  Is your locale set properly?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice in a row. If you don't get an answer the first time, you need to be a bit more patient. If you don't get a good answer the first time, you can use the [edit] button to change your original question, instead of asking it a second time.

Comment: there was some confusion so i added a new question with screenshoots, i forgot that there is edit option as well,

Comment: @Shinrai it has been 1 month when i installed windows. the russian language came just a week before.

Answer (score 2):

FYI (Everybody), if you run a Windows 7 version that doesn’t support multi-language you won’t be able to use the Multilingual User Interface (MUI) functionality to change the default language for Windows 7 welcome screen. Fortunately, MUIs are available in Windows 7 Ultimate and Enterprise edition.

Basically, you are able to change that only when the Keyboards and Languages tab in Region and Language setting looks like below.

[image]
To change the default language on welcome screen

Go to Administrative tab in Region and Language window, which can be launched from Control Panel, and click on Copy settings button.

[image]

You will see what the current language settings on Current user, Welcome screen, and New user account.

[image]

To make the default language setting on Welcome screen the same as your current user account, simply check the option “Welcome screen and system accounts” at the bottom.

[image]

Click OK to save the setting, and reboot the computer for the change to take effect.

Comment: You get it wrong. I am saying about input language. http://superuser.com/questions/398905/russian-language-in-windows-7  see this question, i have explained it with images, hope you will get it,

Comment: I Understand now - please see my respons to your new question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click"Start", then "Control Panel"
2. Hit "Date, Time, Language, and Regional Options", then "Regional and Language Options"
3. Press "Languages" tab, then "Details" button
4. Choose "Langage Bar" button at bottom, and then uncheck "Show the language bar on the desktop"
5. Press "OK" and the Language Bar will be gone 
   Note: You can always just recheck to enable it again

If you really want it gone so you can't ever see it again:

1. Go to "Start", then "Run"
2. Type "Regsvr32.exe /u msutb.dll" and press enter
3. The Language bar will never bother you again

Note: The "Language Bar" button described above will be grayed-out (unaccessible) for good as well, meaning you can never renable it.

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/54819-how-turn-off-language-bar.html)

Comment: russian language is automatically loaded on system restart. i want that it doesnt load,

Comment: It looks more like you've got a windows corruption or using a hacked/cracked version of Windows - my instructions will disable the language bar which will fix your 'problem' regardless of the cause.

Answer (score 0):

run LPKSETUP from the run box or a command prompt - it starts the same program to
maintain the lp.cabs on your machine, as the "regional and language settings" in control panel.

1. Choose "uninstall language pack"

[image: Language Pack uninstall screen]

- Now click on Remove languages option
- Select the language you want to remove and click Next button
- Follow the instructions thereafter.

Comment: i clicked remove langauges but it shows only english language. not russian language is there,

Comment: if you got to Control Panel>Region and language, what is the "Current location" set to on the Location tab?  If you click the link for "Default location" on the bottom of the location tab window, what is your "Default location" set to?